# Java. Обязательно ли использовать this. в коде конструктора, присваивающего значения переменным класса?

Tags: java, конструктор

В конструкторе, предназначенном для присвоения значений переменным класса при создании объекта, иногда использую **this.**, иногда не используют. Я проверил - оба варианта работают, является ли один из них предпочтительным?

```
public class Vehicle {
  private String color;
  Vehicle(String c) {
    color = c;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Vehicle {
  private String color;
  Vehicle(String c) {
    this.color = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Нет не обязательно. Обязательно только если название параметра, переданного в конструктор, совпадает с названием поля класса.

Comment: В Java, в отличии от С(++), служебное слово `this` принято опускать (не использовать), если его использование не требуется явно (обращение к одноименным полям класса и локальным переменным, к примеру)

Comment: СПС. актуальный вопрос задали.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Необязательно, но позволяет не изобретать имена аргументам конструктора:

```
public class Vehicle {

  private String color;

  Vehicle(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Предпочтительно и, в принципе, по другому и не получится в случае, если имя аргумента совпадает с именем поля класса:

```
public class Vehicle {

  private Color color;

  Vehicle(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

В случаях, когда имя параметра отличается от имени поля, которому будет присваиваться значение - слово `this` необязательно. Оно и так будет подразумеваться.